# How to convert base64 from a .b64 file in python?

Tags: python, utf-8, base64, decode

I have tried lots of ways to do it. But it keep showing the original base64 text.
My file is 44.2 MB. So I am thinking that that is the problem.

```
import base64

your_string = open('qq.b64', "rb").read()
a =base64.b64decode(your_string)
print (a)
```

This is the first 100 characers of b64 file.

> Vm0wd2QyUXlVWGxWV0d4V1YwZDRWMVl3WkRSV01WbDNXa1JTVjAxV2JETlhhMUpUVmpBeFYySkVUbGhoTVVwVVZtcEJlRll5U2tW

This is the first 100 characers of output (a).

> b'Vm0wd2QyUXlVWGxWV0d4V1YwZDRWMVl3WkRSV01WbDNXa1JTVjAxV2JETlhhMUpUVmpBeFYySkVUbGhoTVVwVVZtcEJlRll5U2

Comment: This should work, I don't think it has to do with file size. Are you sure you keep getting the original base64 text?

Comment: if you're not sure if the large file causes the problem, why don't you just start with something simple. Create another file and put a short base64 string, e.g. aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=`  into it and test it. What's the result?

Comment: I tried the small file. And it work. But this just show the original text it was.

Comment: What are the values of `print(len(your_string))` and `print(len(a))`? The latter should be about 72% smaller

Comment: @JasonChen : what exactly was the output and what did you expect?

Comment: print(len(your_string)) is 46351293 & print(len(a)) is 34763468

Comment: @jps i expect the output is like a string. Like ANSWER{W3lc0m3_t0_CTF}

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].** File size should have no effect on this.

Comment: @JasonChen: I mean, did you try the example I gave you? Did you get "hello world" as a result? Your result of print(len(,,) shows that `your_String` is 30% larger than `a`, so that seems to be a succesful decoding, because base64 encoded is 30% larger than the original text.

Comment: @jps I try and get exact result you told. Should I just give you guys the file to see if it can work?

Comment: ok, you succesfully decoded a small file. No, I don't want your 44MB file. But [edit] your question and show us the first 100 characers of your b64 file and then the first 100 characters of the output (a)

Comment: @jps ok. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figure it out by myself.
It was encode for 52 times.
so I just try

Comment: great, seems you're right! So if you encode something over and over again, you get a growing sequences of characters in the beginning that doesn't change compared to the previous iteration, thus making it look like nothing changed when you decode it again